# Some questions about SharePoint Workflows

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using SharePoint (I think it's the online 2013 version, it is used directly in IE) to develop an intranet site for a company. For now, I just made some tests (like list/forms and Library) on a "sandbox" site that the administrator made for test purpose.

I know that for my next assignment, I will have to make some forms and workflows for the intranet, and I have some question about the latter:

1. Is it possible to create custom workflow with only SharePoint online?

I don't have all the rights for the "sandbox" site for now, so I can't see if I can do that for now (I'll have the right for the intranet in one or two weeks I think), but I want to prepare myself for when I have it. I know that the company has Nintex Workflow, but it seem that they rather want me to use the default workflow interface of SP.

2. Is it possible with custom workflow to create and add an aspx page to a Document Library when a form is completed on a list ?

**An example:**

- Let's say that on a page I add a list with a form to sign up on the site.
  when the form is complete, it is send to a page with a document library with aspx pages for all people who have signed up
- Inside the pages, there are the info taken from the form and a list of all the modification made to it.
- The list on the first page (the one where the form is first completed) is then emptied.

Comment: Thans for the edition ^^ For Nintex, yeah I know, but like I said, the companie doeson't want me to use it anyway, so the question was for the default interface of sherepoint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is it possible to create custom workflow with only SharePoint online?

Yes, that is possible.
Here is a small tutorial to get you started:

http://techwirenews.com/2012/02/12/creating-simple-workflow-for-sharepoint-online-office-365/

2. Is it possible with custom workflow to create and add an aspx page to a Document Library when a form is completed on a list ?

No, I dont think this is possible with the Default workflow engine on SharePoint online. On premise its definitly possible in combination with sandbox Solutions.

Shows difference between SharePoint Online and on premise:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Plan-customizations-solutions-and-apps-for-SharePoint-Online-b7898ebf-69b7-4196-81e3-b04e1a4e7d67

Comment: Thank you, it'll help greatly. I can't use SharePoint Designer for now (I don't know if it's not installed or if I just don't have the right), but i'll see with the administrator Monday. For the second answer, I'll need to also see with him if he have an ideo how the precedent intern made that then =/ I'll read your link, it seem to be really helpfull :)